# google app engine ndb query error adding delta to date

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to run this query:

```
query = Model.query((Model.created + datetime.timedelta(hours=-6)) => date)
```

however this error is thrown:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DateTimeProperty' and
>   'datetime.timedelta'

The model:

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Can I add a timedelta to a date in a query?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Model.created to datetime.datetime objects and it'll return a datetime.timedelta object that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have a property called `date`.  In your query, you ask for `Model.created`.  Those are not the same.  Try changing both to `date_created` to avoid confusion and conflict.  It's really a bad habit to call variables by common methods or objects, even if they aren't reserved.  Instead of using `date` and `Model`, change to something more descriptive.  Variable conflicts are often hard to find.

So, try:

```
cutoff_time = some_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=-6)
query = MyModelName.query(MyModelName.date_created >= cutoff_time)
```

With:

```
class MyModelName(ndb.Model):
    date_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Also, the proper syntax is `>=`, not `=>`

Comment: I've updated the question, so it's not possible to add a timedelta directly in the query?

Comment: Try the code above.  The error is telling you that `Model.created` is a `DateTimeProperty`, and not an actual property of the entity you want.